# Is there a sense in which this limit is zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, distribution-theory

This question arose from [this answer of mine on DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/46511/19249). Basically, I need to check if this is true:

$$\lim_{M\to \infty} j\frac{\cos[\omega(M+1/2)]}{2\sin(\omega/2)}\stackrel{?}{=}0$$

where $j$ is the imaginary unit (I don't think it's relevant though, we could just drop it), $M\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Note that we are talking about the sequence of functions here, not typical limits.**

This doubt came to me because if the cosine in the numerator was replaced by a sine, then the sequence would converge to $j\pi\delta(\omega)$, where $\delta$ denotes the Dirac delta function. This made me think that maybe there was something similar that could be found out in this case (with the cosine).

I don't know whether this is right or not, but I feel that that limit has to be the zero distribution (if you're interested in the reason, you can check out the link above). Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Does $M\to\infty$ as an integer? as a real? What is $\omega$? can it be any real?

Comment: @robjohn Sorry for not pointing those things out, I've edited the question.

Comment: Judging from comments, I think you mean something involving distributions. This is context that *really really* needs to be expressed! In mathematical settings, the default is usually to assume that you are speaking about the limits of functions, like what you learn in introductory calculus.

Comment: @robjohn Based on the comments to my answer, I think that the question is trying to ask: Consider the sequence $f_n= j\frac{\cos[\omega(n+1/2)]}{2\sin(\omega/2)} $. Do they converge, as distributions to the zero distribution? Which is something completely different than I understood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us interpret functions in question as the following distributions defined in principal-value sense

$$ \forall \varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \ : \quad T_M(\varphi) = \mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos((M+\frac{1}{2})\omega)}{\sin(\omega/2)}\varphi(\omega)  \, d\omega. $$

Splitting the domain of integration according to $2\pi$-periodicity,

\begin{align*}
T_M(\varphi)
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \ \mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos((M+\frac{1}{2})(\omega+2\pi k))}{\sin((\omega+2\pi k)/2)}\varphi(\omega+2\pi k)  \, d\omega \\
&= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left( \frac{\cos((M+\frac{1}{2})\omega)}{\sin(\omega/2)}\varphi(\omega+2\pi k) - \frac{\varphi(2\pi k)}{\omega/2} \right) \, d\omega
\end{align*}

Now writing

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left( \frac{\cos((M+\frac{1}{2})\omega)}{\sin(\omega/2)}\varphi(\omega+2\pi k) - \frac{\varphi(2\pi k)}{\omega/2} \right) \, d\omega \\
&\hspace{4em} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left( \frac{\varphi(\omega+2\pi k)}{\sin(\omega/2)} - \frac{\varphi(2\pi k)}{\omega/2} \right) \cos((M+\tfrac{1}{2})\omega) \, d\omega \\
&\hspace{5em} + \varphi(2\pi k) \underbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos((M+\tfrac{1}{2})\omega) - 1}{\omega/2} \, d\omega}_{=0\text{ by parity}}
\end{align*}

we find that

$$ T_M(\varphi) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \underbrace{\left[ \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \left( \frac{\varphi(\omega+2\pi k)}{\sin(\omega/2)} - \frac{\varphi(2\pi k)}{\omega/2} \right) \right]}_{\in C([-\pi,\pi])} \cos((M+\tfrac{1}{2})\omega) \, d\omega $$

Therefore by the [*Riemann-Lebesgue lemma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma), we have $ \lim_{n\to\infty} T_M(\varphi) = 0 $ and hence $T_M \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true that the limit is zero for all $\omega$.

For example, if $\omega$ is irrational with respect to $\pi$, it follows from the Dirichclet Theorem on density that $\omega(M+1/2) \pmod{2 \pi}$ is dense in $[0, 2 \pi]$.

In particular, if $\frac{\omega}{\pi} \notin \mathbb Q$, it follows from the above that for each $\alpha \in [-1,1]$ there exists an increasing sequence $k_n$ of positive integers such that 
$$\lim_n \cos[\omega(k_n+1/2)] =\alpha$$

It follows that in this case the limit doesn't even exist.

Also, if $\frac{\omega}{\pi} \in \mathbb Q$, the sequence $ \cos[\omega(M+1/2)]$  is periodic. Therefore, it is convergent if and only if it is constant, which happens only for one or two values of $\omega$.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but the two arguments you show don't convince me. If the $\cos()$ in the numerator was replaced by a $\sin()$, I believe both of your arguments would apply, but the limit would equal $j\pi \delta(\omega)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. Namely, the limit would be $0 \ \forall \omega\neq 0$, but there would be an impulse at $\omega =0$. Ergo, I don't think that your answer is enough to say that the limit in the OP isn't $0 \ \forall \omega$.

Comment: I just noticed that what I wrote above isn't exactly true. The limit would not be $0$ for every $\omega\neq 0$, because the impulses would be periodic. So if we replaced the cosine by a sine, the limit would actually equal $0 \ \forall \omega \neq 2k\pi$.

Comment: @Tendero No, even with $\sin$, the limit is NOT $j \pi \delta(\omega)$. It is true that with $\sin$, the sequence of FUNCTIONS converges to $j \pi \delta(\omega)$ in the WEAK-STAR topology on the space of distributions. But this is not what you are asking, and if this is what you are trying to ask, you need to make the question more precise.

Comment: Sorry about that, my knowledge in distribution theory is *very* shallow at the moment. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Tendero And no, if $\omega \neq 2k \pi$ the limit would not be 0. If you have a function periodic over the real line, and restrict it to the intergers, most of the times you don't get a periodic function. Also, a periodic function which is not constant doesn't have a limit at infinity.

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant, but isn't $\delta(\omega)$ zero if $\omega \neq 0$? At least that's what we learn in engineering, where math is not that rigorous, so we use the Dirac delta without much care (although we should). Btw, I've edited the question if you want to take a look at it!

Comment: @Tendero While physicists think about $\delta$ as a function on $\mathbb R$, this is mathematically wrong. Many claims which are true with the correct mathematical definition, and are used a lot, would be mathematically wrong if we thought about it this way. The way in which we think about $\delta$ is a function on the space $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, namely $\delta$ is not a function of numbers, it is a function of functions (namely is measuring functions, not numbers).

Comment: @Tendero Now, for many arguments, physicists think about $\delta$ as a sequences of functions $f_n$, with total area under the graph 1, and for which the support is shrinking down to $0$. If we formalize this, than in teh language of distributions, this interpretation is correct. Indeed, in the weak topology of distributions we have $$\lim_n f_n = \delta$$

Comment: @Tendero But BIG WARNINg coming. Whenever when we say that $\lim_n f_n =\delta$ as distributions, this has absolutely nothing to do with the limit at some or many $x \in \mathbb R$. When we write $$\lim_n f_n =\delta$$ as distributions, the exact meaning is the following: for all $f$ functions which are infinitely many times differentiable and compactly supported we have $$\lim_n \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) f_n(t) dt = f(0)$$

Comment: Wow, that was so clear and inspiring. I hope I'll be able to study about distribution theory some day. Thank you for your detailed explanation!